# Prove that a functional is convex

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$. We define the functional $\Phi$ as:

\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}(Tx,x)
\end{equation}

My exercise says that $\Phi$ is convex if $T$ is strictly positive. I know that I have to prove that for $x,y \in H, t\in[0,1]$ it holds:

\begin{equation}
\Phi(tx+(1-t)y)\leq t\Phi(x)+(1-t)\Phi(y)
\end{equation}
but until now I have managed to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\Phi(tx+(1-t)y)=t^2\Phi(x)+t(1-t)((Tx,y)+(Ty,x))+(1-t)^2\Phi(y)
\end{equation}
I know that I have to use the fact that $T$ is strictly positive, but I do not see how to do that..

Comment: If you are free to choose the path of proof and are stuck with the one you have chosen, then alternatively you may show that the function $t\mapsto \langle T(x+ty), x+ty \rangle $ is convex on $[0,1]$ for every $x,y$ (Why?). Since this is real function which is quite obviously smooth, you can calculate the second derivative and check whether it is positive.

Comment: @Thomas I am not able to see why would this prove the statement above :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the proof you can observe that since $T$ is self-adjoint, positive, and bounded it has a square-root.  Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Phi(tx+(1-t)y) &=& t^2\Phi(x)+t(1-t)((Tx,y)+(Ty,x))+(1-t)^2\Phi(y) \\
&=& t^2\Phi(x)+t(1-t)((T^{1/2}x,T^{1/2}y)+(T^{1/2}y,T^{1/2}x))+(1-t)^2\Phi(y) \\
&\leq& t^2\Phi(x)+2t(1-t)(T^{1/2}x,T^{1/2}x)(T^{1/2}y,T^{1/2}y)+(1-t)^2\Phi(y) \\
&=& t^2\Phi(x)+2t(1-t)\sqrt{\Phi(x)\Phi(y)}+(1-t)^2\Phi(y) \\
&=& \left(t\sqrt{\Phi(x)}+(1-t)\sqrt{\Phi(y)}\right)^2 \\
&=& t\Phi(x)+(1-t)\Phi(y) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The last line follows from Jensen's inequality applied to $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thank you! ok two questions: 1) Why the square root and 2) I do not know about the Jensen's inequality, which form did you use here, since at wiki I could not exactly understand the connection.

Comment: @Mitscaype  I added the Jensen step in there explicitly.  It comes directly from the statement that $x^2$ is convex.  Regarding why the square root.  I needed it to apply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality in line three.

Comment: Thank you! But I cannot see how can I write $(Tx,y)+(Ty,x)=(T^{1/2}x,T^{1/2}y)+(T^{1/2}y,T^{1/2}x)$? :/

Comment: @Mitscaype  The square root is self-adjoint.  Since $T=(T^{1/2})^2$, you can move one of the roots over to the RHS of the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use this identity for quadratic forms:
$$ Q(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) = \lambda Q(x) + (1-\lambda) Q(y) - \lambda (1-\lambda) Q(x-y). $$
It's then pretty obvious that $\lambda (1-\lambda) Q(x-y)>0$ if $0<\lambda<1$ and $Q>0$, so the convexity is obvious.

---

Now, you may be concerned about this identity applying here. $\Phi(x)=(Tx,x)$ is a quadratic form for real scalars:
$$ \Phi(\lambda x) = (T(\lambda x,\lambda x) = \lvert \lambda \rvert^2 (Tx,x) = \lambda^2 (Tx,x) = \lambda^2 \Phi(x), $$
and
$$ \Phi(x+y)-\Phi(x)-\Phi(y) = (T(x+y),x+y)-(Tx,x)-(Ty,y) = (Tx,y)+(Ty,x), $$
and $(T(\lambda x),y)+(Ty,\lambda x)=\bar{\lambda}(Tx,y)+\lambda(Ty,x)= \lambda((Tx,y)+(Ty,x))$. We are considering real $\lambda$, so this is all fine.

---

The identity itself is quite straightforward to prove: if $Q(x+y)-Q(x)-Q(y)=2B(x,y)$ is the bilinear,
$$ Q(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \lambda^2 Q(x)+(1-\lambda)^2 Q(y) + \lambda (1-\lambda) 2B(x,y) \\
= \lambda^2 Q(x)+(1-\lambda)^2 Q(y) + \lambda (1-\lambda) \left( Q(x)+Q(y)-Q(x-y) \right) \\
= \left( \lambda^2+\lambda(1-\lambda) \right)Q(x) + \left( (1-\lambda)^2 +\lambda (1-\lambda) \right)Q(y) -\lambda(1-\lambda)Q(x-y) \\
= \lambda Q(x) + (1-\lambda) Q(y) -\lambda(1-\lambda)Q(x-y). $$